# Is there a way to root a locked Motorola phone?

Tags: rooting, password, locked-out, bootloader-lock

Someone gave me their locked phone and I want to install a custom rom on it but it's not rooted and developer options aren't enabled. The phone model is Motorola Moto G6 Play.

Comment: What means "locked"? SIM locked, mobile network locked, screen locked, bootloader locked?

Comment: Locked like they forgot the password and don't know the email (it's a child)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bypass "Verify your account" (Factory Reset Protection)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootloader Unlock Question: Motorola](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213699/bootloader-unlock-question-motorola)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the various ways an android phone can be locked?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230829/what-are-the-various-ways-an-android-phone-can-be-locked)